# Can I assign multiple values to a proto message from a tuple?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I need to create an list of proto rows from a list of tuples.

I can only see that I can create a message by explicitly referencing the fields like

```
customer = customer_pb2.customer()
customer.user_id = 1
customer.name = 'Mary'
```

But let's say I have a list of tuples like [(1, 'Mark'), (2, 'Mary')] - how can I quickly and succinctly create a row from my pb2 file and the data from the tuple to it? Is there a way without explicitly referencing the names like in the example above? It would be nice to be able to do something out of the box like

```
customer = customer_pb2.customer()
customer.append((my_tuple))
```

Comment: To my knowledge, no (there isn't). But, it's straightforward to write one for your messages.

Comment: Yes, I've written a little function to assign the values, thanks. I was lazily hoping for an in-built method I missed :)